# Convert Model Class to ReactiveMongo BSONDocument

Tags: json, mongodb, reactivemongo

I have a case class which is a model object in my application and goes like this:

```
case class MyModel(myTypeA: TypeA, str: String)
case class TypeA(intVal: Int, strVal: String)
```

I'm using MongoDB and the ReactiveMongo library for my persistence needs. I would like to convert this type to the BSONDocument so that I could persist this. I do not want to use the play reactive mongo module as I will be moving away from Play framework and use Spray at a later stage. I understand that I should write implicit conversions between BSON and my model types. As a starter, I have done the following:

```
implicit object MyModelBSONHandler extends BSONDocumentReader[MyModel] with BSONDocumentWriter[MyModel] {
  def read(doc: BSONDocument) = {
    MyModel(
      str = doc.getAs[String]("str").get,
      type = doc.getAs[TypeA]("myTypeA").get
    )
  }
  def write(myModel: MyModel) = {
    BSONDocument(
      "str" -> myModel.str,
      "myTypeA" -> myModel.myTypeA // Is this correct?
    )
  }
}

implicit object TypeABSONHandler extends BSONDocumentReader[TypeA] with BSONDocumentWriter[TypeA] {
  def read(doc: BSONDocument) = {
    TypeA(
      doc.getAs[Int]("intVal").get,
      doc.getAs[String]("strVal").get
    )
  }
  def write(typeA: TypeA) = {
    BSONDocument(
      "intVal" -> typeA.intVal,
      "strVal" -> typeA.strVal
    )
  }
}
```

As it can be seen, I'm not sure on how to write complex BSON types? I'm yet to give this a try in my code base!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use implicit handler value in object companion via `Macros`. Its more simple and elegant way to do this. [There are](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/macros/src/main/scala/interface.scala) some complex handler examples in class docs.

```
import reactivemongo.bson.Macros

case class MyModel(myTypeA: TypeA, str: String)

object MyModel{
    implicit val handler = Macros.handler[MyModel]
}

case class TypeA(intVal: Int, strVal: String)

object TypeA{
    implicit val handler = Macros.handler[TypeA]
}

class class Foo(n: Int, model: MyModel, tpe: TypeA, date: Long,
                name: String/* and so on */ )

object Foo{
   //and simple handler in one line of code
   implicit val handler = Macros.handler[TypeA]
}
```

I use custom handlers where needed a very specific behavior, other cases are quite covered with macros.

Comment: Cool! I will give this a try tonight! Thanks for the post!